# Prove for a random variable $X$,$(E|X|^2)^2\le E|X|E|X|^3$

Tags: probability-theory

More general, for $\alpha\in[0,2)$, is $(E|X|^2)^2\le E|X|^{2-\alpha}E|X|^{2+\alpha}$ always true?

I don't have any idea to deal with such inequality concerning three expectations. Can someone give an idea on proving it? Thank you!

Comment: Apply [Cauchy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) with $f=|X|^{(2-a)/2}$, $g=|X|^{(2+a)/2}$.

Comment: Thank you so much!